# Windows like Alt-Tab (Cmd Tab)

Tags: macos, keyboard, mojave, productivity

Is there a way to tab through all active windows in Mac OS (Mojave 10.14.5) like in Win 7,8,10? I would like to do this on my work computer, so a native solution would be appreciated; rather than one where I would have to install a 3rd party service.

Sorry if this has been asked/answered before; I couldn't find a proper response.

Thanks